# Class, interface or enum expected 14 errors

Tags: class, interface, enums

I'm trying to do an incometax program and keep getting 14 of these errors.
Please help.

```
 /*
 *Printing IncomeTax
 *9/7/15
 */


import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncomeTax 
{
    public static void main(String[] args);
    {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("---Income Tax Program---\n\n\n");
    System.out.print("Your income:");
    double income = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter your filling status(S-Single,M-Married,J-JointlyFiling");
    char filing=keyboard.next().charAt(0);

     System.out.print("Enter the number of deductions you are claiming:");
     int deductions = keyboard.nextInt();
     double taxableIncome = taxableIncome(income,deductions);
     double taxPercent = taxPercent(filingStatus,taxIncome);
     double owedAmount = taxableIncome*taxPercent;
     double takeHome= income-owedAmount;
     double taxPercent2=taxPercent*100;
     System.out.print("Income tax Information: ");
     System.out.printf("\nIncome- %.2f",income);
     System.out.print("Filing status:"+filing);
     System.out.printf("Taxable Income- %.2f",taxabeIncome);
     System.out.printf("Tax percentage:"+taxPercent1+"%");
     System.out.printf("Tax owed: "+owedAmount);
     System.out.printf("Take Home: "+takeHome); 

    }
}


public static double taxableIncome(double income,double deductions)
   {
    double taxIncome = income-5000-1000*deductions;
   if (income>0)
     return taxableIncome;
   else
    return 0;

   }
   public static double taxPercent(char filingStatus,double taxableIncome)
   {

    double taxPercent
    if (taxIncome<=30000 && taxIncome>=0)
    else if(filingStatus==S)
            return==.05;
     else if (filingStatus==M)
        return==.08;
     else ( filing status==J)
        return==.10;
   }

   {
         if (taxIncome<L=50000 && taxIncome>30000)
        else if ( filingStatus == S)
            return==.10;
            else if(filingStatus == M)
                return==.16;
            else (filingStatus==J)
                return==.20;
    }

    {
             if (taxIncome>50000)
            else if(filingStatus == S)
                    return==.20;
                else if (filingStatus == M)
                    return ==.24;
                else (filingStaus == J)
                    return==.30;    
  }
```

> --------------------Configuration: -------------------- C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:41: error: class, interface,
>   or enum expected    public static double taxableIncome(double
>   income,double deductions)
>                    ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:44: error: class, interface, or enum expected    if (income>0)    ^
>   C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:46: error: class, interface,
>   or enum expected    else    ^
>   C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:49: error: class, interface,
>   or enum expected    }    ^
>   C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:50: error: class, interface,
>   or enum expected    public static double taxPercent(char
>   filingStatus,double taxableIncome)
>                    ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:57: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>        else if (filingStatus==M)
>        ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:59: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>        else ( filing status==J)
>        ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:61: error: class, interface, or enum expected    }    ^
>   C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:67: error: class, interface,
>   or enum expected
>               else if(filingStatus == M)
>               ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:69: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>               else (filingStatus==J)
>               ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:71: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>       }
>       ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:77: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>                   else if (filingStatus == M)
>                   ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:79: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>                   else (filingStaus == J)
>                   ^ C:\Users\Tazeen\Downloads\IncomeTax.java:81: error: class, interface, or enum expected   }   ^ 14 errors

Process completed.

Answer (score 0):

The method is not in the class; move it inside the 2nd curly brace.

Sorry, this code is a complete mess.  There's everything wrong with it.

You don't seem to care enough to pay any attention to what you're doing.  Either start paying attention or give up coding today.

```
 /*
 *Printing IncomeTax
 *9/7/15
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070915/class-interface-or-enum-expected-14-errors/33070940#3307094010
 */


import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncomeTax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Your income:");
        double income = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter your filling status(S-Single,M-Married,J-JointlyFiling");
        char filingStatus = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of deductions you are claiming:");
        int deductions = keyboard.nextInt();
        double taxableIncome = getTaxableIncome(income, deductions);
        double taxPercent = getTaxPercent(filingStatus, taxableIncome);
        double owedAmount = taxableIncome * taxPercent;
        double takeHome = income - owedAmount;
        double taxPercent1 = taxPercent * 100;
        System.out.println("Income tax Information: ");
        System.out.println("Income: " + income);
        System.out.println("Filing status: " + filingStatus);
        System.out.println("Taxable Income: " +  taxableIncome);
        System.out.println("Tax percentage: " + taxPercent1);
        System.out.println("Tax owed: " + owedAmount);
        System.out.println("Take Home: " + takeHome);
    }

    public static double getTaxableIncome(double income, int numDeductions) {
        double taxableIncome = income - 5000 - 1000 * numDeductions;
        return (taxableIncome > 0.0 ? taxableIncome : 0.0);
    }

    public static double getTaxPercent(char filingStatus, double taxableIncome) {
        double taxPercent = 0.0;
        if (taxableIncome >= 0 && taxableIncome <= 30000) {
            if (filingStatus == 'S') {
                taxPercent = .05;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'M') {
                taxPercent = .08;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'J') {
                taxPercent = .10;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown tax percent");
            }
        } else if  (taxableIncome > 30000 && taxableIncome <= 50000) {
            if (filingStatus == 'S') {
                taxPercent = .10;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'M') {
                taxPercent = .16;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'J') {
                taxPercent = .20;
            }
        } else if (taxableIncome > 50000) {
            if (filingStatus == 'S') {
                taxPercent = .20;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'M') {
                taxPercent = .24;
            } else if (filingStatus == 'J') {
                taxPercent = .30;
            }
        }
        return taxPercent;
    }
}
```